# How to evaluate social/emotional development?

Tags: social-development, research, milestones, emotional-development

I know there are many books on evaluating academic success and deficits, but how do you evaluate social/emotional learning?  Are there studies to help with this? What milestones should a parent look for?  Should the amount of schooling in the younger years be factored into the evaluation as the child started learning social skills at a younger age?

Comment: What is the point? What changes would less than stellar results lead you to make?  Perhaps you should just make those changes ...

Comment: @tomjedrz:  I assumed when I was answering the question that morah was using this as a way to determine areas of "need" for her children (as I periodically do) so that she can make a gameplan to work on these areas with her kids.  However, it helps to know what is socially/emotionally expected out of a kid before you start being concerned about it.  For example, we are currently working on sharing and using our words--perfectly acceptable expectations for my 4 year old, not so much for my 1 year old.  Please feel free to correct me if I misinterpreted any of this, morah.

Comment: What do you mean what is the point @tomjedrz ?  Social/emotional is just as important as academic development and some would say more important.  Ensuring that my kids are on track is extremely important to ensuring a happy well adjusted child.

Comment: @morahhochman:  I would +100 that if I could.  I think sometimes parents tend to overlook social/emotional development assuming that kids will just figure it out for themselves.

Comment: @all "It helps to know what is socially/emotionally expected ... " is the problem. How can it be measured?  If the goal is a "happy well adjusted child", then evaluate if your child is happy and well adjusted. If not, find out what and help your child. If yes, then who cares if the child has fewer friends than peers, or doesn't text message 100x/day, or only gets 1 birthday party invitation a month, or whatever measure some academic comes up with. This is one area where you should TRUST YOUR INSTINCTS.

Comment: I abhor the "Stepford child" attitude I see so frequently. On no, my child isn't "normal". There is no "normal", just as there is no "average". We spend far too much time and effort applying standards to our kids and then worrying about differences.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this will help you, but I found a study published online from January 2011 for the Raikes Foundation entitled "[Social-Emotional Learning Assessment Measures for Middle School Youth](http://raikesfoundation.org/Documents/SELTools.pdf)".  I know it seems to focus primarily on middle school ages, but it seems to have some information in it that talks a little bit about social-emotional assessment in younger ages, and it includes several samples of assessments towards the end.  The reference page is a solid two pages, so there might be some literature in there that would help you some.  Fair warning:  It's about 50 pages long so you might want to settle in with a big cup of coffee after the kids have gone to bed :-D